# How to access contents of Folders created by user in Lotus Notes Using .NET?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am getting contents of all views (Folders).Like Inbox,Calendar,ToDo e.t.c.

As mentioned in Title i want to access contents of Folders created my user.
For Example "Folder1" and sub-folder "ABC"

I can do it as:

```
 NotesView folder = _notesDatabase.GetView("(Folder1)");
 NotesDocument docFolder = folder.GetFirstDocument();
```

For sub-folder :  `NotesView folder = _notesDatabase.GetView("(Folder1/ABC)");`

But here i need to specify folder name.Which can't be known in advance.
So i can't hard code it.

Is there any way to get only list of User created Folders and Sub-folders?

Comment: Hi Preeti - you've asked a lot of questions on StackOverflow but it doesn't appear you accept that many (you're at 8% right now).  Reputation is an important part of this site, so please accept any answers that are accurate.

Comment: Thanx Ken. Actually i didn't knew about importance of acceptance part of any ans or Reputation earned by me on Stack Overflow.As i am new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all folders in a mailbox, use `NotesDatabase.Views` and the `isFolder` property. Then you can either explicitly exclude ($Inbox), ($Junkmail) et.c. or use the heuristic that folders where the name begins with "(" are system folders:

```
Dim session As New notessession

Forall fa_view In session.currentdatabase.views
    If fa_view.isFolder() Then
        If Left$(fa_view.name,1) <> "(" Then    Print fa_view.name
    End If
End Forall
```

Ken Pespisas suggestion to use `isPrivate` is nicer and will work unless users are allowed to create shared folders. I'm not sure if this is the default Notes access or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a collection of views using the NotesDatabase Views property

```
_notesDatabase.Views
```

If you loop through that collection, you can inspect each view's IsPrivate property to see if it is a private view created by the user.  In Lotusscript it would look like this

```
Dim allViews as Variant
Set allViews = _notesDatabase.Views
ForAll myview In allViews
    If myview.IsPrivate Then
        'Do something
    End If
End ForAll
```